# Can a symmetric matrix B always be expressed in the form $A^T A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I ask this because I'm having confusion between the Spectral Theorem and a different theorem. Spectral Theorem states that the eigen values of a symmetric matrix B are real (not necessarily positive) whilst the eigenvalues of a matrix$ A^T A $ are real AND positive. I assume the answer to my original question is no, but why?

Comment: This looks similar to the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Comment: $B = UDU^T$ where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal with the real eigenvalues. If the values on the diagonal are non-negative, then we can define as "square root" $D^{1/2}$ of $D$ with the square root of the values of $D$ on the diagonal such that $B=UD^{1/2}D^{1/2}U^T=A^TA$ where $A:= D^{1/2}U^T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $A^TA$ is positive semidefinite for any $A$, and hence it has nonnegative eigenvalues. Thus the matrix $$B=-I $$ is not expressible in this form.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say "$A^T A$ is nonnegative definite for any $A$" instead?

Comment: @StubbornAtom it definitely sounds better, but I've decided to follow the terminology of Wikipedia here.

Comment: I assume we're not considering imaginary matrices? Because $-I = (iI)^T(iI)$ where $\cdot^T$ denotes transpose and not conjugate transpose.

Comment: @mathisfun That's my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is a symmetric real matrix, then $det(B)\in \mathbb{R}$. But $\det(A^T A)=\det(A^T)\det(A)=(\det(A))^2\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ as $A$ is also a real matrix. So consider the real symmetric matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ which has determinant $-1$ and has no decomposition that you suggested.

Comment: Should have clarified that the "it" meant what I wrote.